# How could devcoin keep the miners get only 10% of the coins?

Tags: bitcoin

How could devcoin keep the miners get only 10% of the coins?Can it prevent the miners cheat the  developers,like change some docs in the source code or client?
thank you very much for helping me

Answer (score -1):

Mining is computationally complex, but is easy to verify. Network verifies each transaction and reject invalid ones. Miner can try publish invalid transaction, but it won't pass verification and won't be approved/

Comment: oh,though I still really don't know how it works,but thank you all the same,could you give some advice to me to learn the network verifies ?I really want to get it